# useEffect runs only once and after refresh it does not fetch again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this component that fetches data from a site, and tries to get its keys.
The problem is that it works fine at the first time, but when I refresh the page / save the project in VSCode (and the project refreshes automatically) it shows this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
  14 |    )
  15 | 
  16 |    return (
> 17 |        <div className="rates">
     | ^  18 |            {Object.keys(rates.rates).map(
  19 |                rate => <Button variant="outlined">
  20 |                    {rate}
```

The code (the specific component):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';


const RatesCard = () => {

    const [rates, setRates] = useState([]);
    useEffect(
        ()=>{
            fetch("https://api.vatcomply.com/rates")
            .then(ratesResponse => ratesResponse.json())
            .then(rates => setRates(rates));
        }
    ,[])

    return (
        <div className="rates">
            {Object.keys(rates.rates).map(
                rate => <Button variant="outlined">
                    {rate}
                </Button>
            )}
        </div>
        )
    }
    

export default RatesCard
```

I have no idea why it works the first time and then it doesn't. My guess is that the `useEffect` hook runs only once because of the `[]` dependency, and then when we refresh it says "Nothing changed, so I won't run the function" Thus we don't fetch anything, and thus `rates` is `undefined`...

I have no clue why it does this, I can only guess. I will appreciate your kind help! Thank you!

Comment: Your default value for rates should be an empty object, not empty array.
Change your state definition to the following: `const [rates, setRates] = useState({rates:[]});`

Comment: @SuthanBala Thank you it works! I would also like an explanation about why it happens, what went wrong because I am new to reactjs. Many thanks sir!

Comment: Updated my answer with the explanation. Let me know if you need more explanation on anything..

Comment: You should use `.then(({ rates }) => setRates(rates));` and `Object.keys(rates).map`, that way the intial state `[]` for `rates` is fine. Wrapping the array in an otherwise empty object is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useEffect` runs after your component is mounted
which means `rates` is just an empty array that doesn't have a property called `rates`

```
Object.keys(rates.rates)
```

try to use

```
const [rates, setRates] = useState({rates:[]});
```

or make a loading indicator for example

```
const RatesCard = () => {

    const [rates, setRates] = useState([]);
    useEffect(
        ()=>{
            fetch("https://api.vatcomply.com/rates")
            .then(ratesResponse => ratesResponse.json())
            .then(rates => setRates(rates));
        }
    ,[])


    if(rates.length === 0) {
        return <h1> loading </hi>
     }
    return (
        <div className="rates">
            {Object.keys(rates.rates).map(
                rate => <Button variant="outlined">
                    {rate}
                </Button>
            )}
        </div>
        )
```

Comment: So what happens is that react is "super quick" trying to access `Object.keys(rates.rates)` but can't because we haven't fetched it, but why it happens before though? The fetch is the first thing that happens after all no?

Comment: yes, exactly 
that's why they put a loading spinner or skeleton before fetching data
also remember that `fetch` takes some time and doesn't occur immediately 
for more info check React Life Cycle

Answer (score 1):

Your default value for rates should be an empty object with `rates` property set to an empty array (`{rates: []}`).

By saying the following `Object.keys(rates.rates).map` you're going with the assumption that the `rates` will be an object, and `rates.rates` will be an array.

It works the "first" time due to how hot reloading works, because when you save your files, it injects codes to the browser and not remounting the entire app. Thus, your app will continue from where it left off before, even if it crashed on the previous load..

Change your state definition to the following: const [rates, setRates] = useState({rates:[]});

This will ensure when your app tries to run `Object.keys(rates.rates).map` it doesn't crash because you have an array to iterate not `null`/`undefined`

Comment: `const [details, setDetails] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof props.logindetails.Username !== 'undefined'){
      setDetails(props.logindetails.Username);
    } else {
      setDetails('You Need To Login First !!!');
    }
  }, [props, props.logindetails]);`
This too has undefined value after refreshing, any solution?
@SuthanBala